# displaying random contents with php

Tags: php, text, random

I have a script with that it write a site url and site name in this format :

```
::<a href='http://master7np.tk>Master7np</a>::<a href='http://master-land.net>
Master-land</a>::<a href='http://nischal.tk>nischal.tk</a>
```

I want a php script that display this random url from point `::` in a webpage

here is the original, but it is not working--I mean it only displays:

```
"<a href='http://master7np.tk>Master7np</a>"
```

but it should display randomly (not just the first one).

```
<?
$xfile = @file("/home/webtraff/public_html/ads.txt");
$random_num = rand (0,count($xfile)-1);
$udata = explode("::",$xfile[$random_num]);
echo "$udata[1]";
?>
```

Comment: Well, you are selecting a random line from the input file. But then keep using `[1]` for the broken up parts in said line, but not a random number.

Answer (score 0):

Your instruction order is bit off. i changed how you read the file.

```
$file = file_get_contents("/home/webtraff/public_html/ads.txt"); //open the file as string removed the
$udata = explode("::",$file); //then we split by tokens
$udata = array_flip($udata); //change the values to keys
$text = array_rand($udata); //get a random key
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code as following

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("/home/webtraff/public_html/ads.txt"); //open the file 
$urls = explode("::",$data); //url split by separator
$number=rand(0,count($urls)-1); // Get random number
echo $urls[$number];  //random output
```

?>

Comment: bro its not displaying sometime. it gives blank output

Comment: ::<a href='http://master7np.tk>Master7np</a>::<a href='http://master-land.net>
Master-land</a>::<a href='http://nischal.tk>nischal.tk</a>

if your file start with :: then explode function store a blank element in array. so it return sometimes blank output.
so remove starting :: point.

Comment: you mean jst remove the first :: or remove all :: from the script??

Comment: ya thanks i remove the :: from the first and its working nice thanks :)